# What will travel across regional connections?

Tags: simcity-2013

For each of the regional connection types (road, rail, water, air):

- What services can be shared?
- What resources can be traded/consumed?
- What types of sims will travel, and what causes them to want to travel?
- What buildings need to be plopped to allow travel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gifts and resources can be traded with any city with which you have a rail, air, road, or ferry connection. The connections are created by plopping the appropriate mass transit building in each city. Worker and shopper sims will "commute" over these connections as well but the actual commuting is a rough simulation.

Services such as power, water, garbage, police, health, etc (pretty much everything else) can only be shared with cities with which you have a road connection with.